# Textbox in Custom View

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created a custom View to handle drawing in the application and its working well. Bu i can't seem to add a text box to the the top of the drawing area. It either does not show up or completely replaces the draw view.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DrawView drawView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);      
    drawView = new DrawView(this);
    drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setContentView(drawView);
    drawView.requestFocus();
}
}
```

I tries adding a new content view and added the text box in it but then it replaces the drawing area.
Then i tried adding the text view inside the draw view class but did not know to add it. If i add the text box in the activity layout, it does not appear too.

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path   mPath;
private Paint  mPaint;     
private EditText editText;

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
}
```

What is the best approach to add elements to the UI ? I want to add buttons later to the view as well

Comment: Have you tried to place then with XML code an set visible as false? Then you only must setvisible=true in your java code and they will appear

Comment: Yes. but the draw view still takes up the full screen.

Comment: which parameters are you using for your layout editText?